# InternalsVisibleTo for Matlab/something other than .NET

Tags: c#, matlab

I am in the process of porting a algorithm implementation from Matlab to C#.  In order to test the port, I would like to use the same set of suits that have all ready been developed in matlab and test both implementations and compare the results.

The library consists of one public interface + several internal algorithms which need to be tested separately.  Testing the public interface is no problem.

But testing the internal classes is proving quite difficult.  I'm looking for a way of exposing the innards of the libary to something other than .NET.  I'm aware of InternalsVisibleTo but this seems to require a .NET assembly name.

Can anyone help?  I really don't want to have to re-write the tests as C# unit tests.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import the .NET libraries directly into MATLAB (needs a recent version) and call its methods at the command line. So perhaps you could run the same test suite you already have.

If it's a private method, then just expose it temporarily somehow for testing.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but what I'm looking for is how to "expose it temporarily somehow for testing".  Ideally by not having to go though and change everything to public just to have to then change it back for the release version.